# Find limit of this recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
a_0=0,\ a_1=2,\ a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2 - \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}} \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}2^na_n\ =\ ?
$$

Comment: I might try rewriting the sequence in terms of $b_n = 2^n a_n$.

Comment: Take the limit of both sides of the recursion and solve for the $a_n$ limit assuming it exists.

Comment: @RRL: I'd like to see how you would do that!

Comment: Any way to solve this just from the recursion without using $a_n=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$?

Answer (score 7):

Let's prove by induction that
$$
a_n=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)
$$
Let $\theta_n=\pi/2^n$. Clearly, $2\sin(\pi)=0=a_0$ and $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=2=a_1$. Furthermore,
$$
a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}}=2\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_n}}{2}}
$$
But
$$
\frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_n}=\frac{\sin \theta_{n-1}}{2\sin\theta_n}=
\frac{\sin 2\theta_n}{2\sin\theta_n}=
\frac{2\sin \theta_n\cos\theta_n}{2\sin\theta_n}=\cos\theta_n
$$
and
$$
\cos2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha
$$
$$
\sin\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos 2\alpha}{2}}
$$
Hence,
$$
a_{n+1}=2\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta_n}{2}}=
2\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}=2\sin\theta_{n+1}
$$
Using Taylor series expansion,
$$
a_n=2\theta_n+O\left(\theta_n^3\right)=
\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}+O\left(8^{-n}\right)
$$
so
$$
2^n a_n=2\pi+O\left(4^{-n}\right)\to 2\pi
$$

Comment: There's a minor error. $a_n = 2 \sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$ so that $a_0 = 2 \sin(\pi) = 0$ and $a_1 = 2 \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2$. So the limit would be $2 \pi$ instead.

Comment: I've edited away the error. Anyway it's a nice solution! And by the way it is one of the formulae at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html.

Comment: @user21820 Oops, you're right. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer.  I'll complete it if I can, or someone else can take over.

A little fiddling around shows that

$$\begin{align}
a_2&=\sqrt2\\
a_3&=\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}\\
a_4&=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}\\
a_5&=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}\\
\end{align}$$

at which point the pattern should be clear, so the question boils down to how quickly does

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}$$

approach its limit, which is easily shown to be $2$.

Comment: oops I'm silly, had an algebra error on my paper!

Comment: It's $2\cos\left(\pi/2^n\right)$, as can be shown by half-angle formula starting with e.g. $\pi$. You beat me to it ;) I hope now you can complete the answer. Hint: first two terms of Taylor series are enough.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś, do you want to post a complete solution (or hint) as a separate answer?  You should get credit for it.